# Why can't CreateEvent be used as a value in a blueprint Map?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, events, delegates

I need to map `Button` to `Event`, seeing as Unreal does not allow me to call premade events (in this situation, `OnHovered` for `Buttons`)

---

When you connect a `CreateEvent` to something like a `Timer`, you have the option to choose a delegate, as shown:

[image]

---

However, when you connect this to the value in a Map, you do not get to choose, despite the connection being allowed.

[image]

---

**Tl;Dr:**

Why can I not use event delegates as a value in a pair map?

Comment: I dint know why it behaves so. But as a workaround I think it is better to subclass that button and handle all the bells and whistles there :-|

Comment: UMG is the bane of my existence

Comment: Welcome to the club...